# What's causing "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error?

Tags: javascript

```
$(function(){
 $.getJSON("http://wallkeeper.com/wj/api/posts?s=" + document.getElementById("searchTxt").value, function(data){
    var template = $('#posts-list').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    $('#allposts').html(html);
    });
});
```

This is used used to get the search result json. But I am getting the following error. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: You missed the `+` before `document.getElementById()`. Also you should remove the `;""` after it.

Comment: I changed it  '$.getJSON("http://wallkeeper.com/wj/api/posts?s=" + document.getElementById("searchTxt").value"", function(data){  but still getting the same error...

Comment: In the edited question you made one-and-a-half of the two changes I suggested, so yes, you've still got a syntax error.

Comment: It has been removed. Was a typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missed + sign and has a unneeded ;

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://wallkeeper.com/wj/api/posts?s=" + document.getElementById("searchTxt").value+"", function (data) {
        var template = $('#posts-list').html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#allposts').html(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: It shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: do you have an `input` field with `id` **searchTxt** ??

Comment: Yes <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="searchTxt" type="text" class="validate">

Comment: The error is exactly what is wrong. A variable or value u think exists is coming back null. Console.log your values and double check or add a debugger to your backend code/breakpoint if this code is ran in the browser.

Comment: Just put this in your code. console.log(document.getElementById('searchTxt'))

Comment: put `document.getElementById("searchTxt")` in your console and check if it returns anything

Comment: Oh I know what's wrong. You're missing brackets on .value()

Comment: @powerup7 brackets are not needed

Comment: @Niraula oh? Maybe Im too used to jquery. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `""` after the `value`.

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://wallkeeper.com/wj/api/posts?s=" + document.getElementById("searchTxt").value, function(data){
        var template = $('#posts-list').html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#allposts').html(html);
    });
});
```

Comment: It shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: Then that means `searchTxt` doesn't exist. Are you sure that's the id of the search textbox?